# How can a Service Account be Restricted to ONLY access the vision-api?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

What is the best way to restrict a service account to the vision-api?

There are not obvious pre-defined roles that seems appropriate (or if there are, they are not named in an obvious way)

Before suggesting use of API key instead of `service-account.json`, consider that the Google Client API (which may wrap the REST api??) only seems to support use of ADC via an environment variable that points to the `service-account.json` file.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PATH_TO_KEY_FILE`

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible.
You should subscribe to this ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66035125